# sort numpy array elements by the value of a condition on the elements

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, proximity

I need to sort a numpy array of points by increasing distance from another point.

```
import numpy as np

def dist(i,j,ip,jp): 
    return np.sqrt((i-ip)**2+(j-jp)**2)

arr = np.array([[0,0],[1,2],[4,1]])
```

What I would like to do is use function dist(1,1,ip,jp) between a fixed point [i,j]=[1,1] and each ordered pair [ip,jp] in arr to return arr with each element sorted from lowest to highest proximity to [i,j]. Anyone have a quick solution for this?

The output I want is new_arr = np.array([[1,2],[0,0],[4,1]])

I have some ideas but they're wildly inefficient seeming.

Thanks!

Comment: This is one way: `np.array(sorted(arr, key=lambda x: dist(1,1,x[0], x[1])))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realize now this is a popular question, so years later, here's my own answer which uses the extremely powerful functionality of `scipy.spatial`. Here, `scipy.spatial.cdist` is used to do the distance computations. This is lightning fast and pythonic, without any "convert to list and convert back" hackery:

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist
import numpy as np

# EXAMPLE DATA
arr = 20*np.random.random(size=(5000000,2))-10 # testing data
pt = np.array([[1,1]]) # the point to eval proximity to

# THE SOLUTION
out = arr[np.argsort(cdist(arr,pt).squeeze())]
```

Here, `cdist` gets an array of distances, `squeeze` kills the extra dimension in this array, `argsort` orders the indices into the distances by the distances, and `arr[...]` sorts `arr` by these indices.

Answer (score 12):

There seem to be two ways to do this:

1. Convert the whole numpy array into a Python list, and sort it using Python's sort method with a key function.

   ```
    l = list(arr)
    l.sort(key=lambda coord: dist(1, 1, coord[0], coord[1]))
    arr = np.array(l)
   ```
2. Create a second numpy array by mapping `dist()` over the original array, use `.argsort()` to get the sorted order, then apply that to the original array.

   ```
    arr2 = np.vectorize(lambda coord: dist(1, 1, coord[0], coord[1]))(arr)
    arr3 = np.argsort(arr2)
    arr = np.array(arr)[arr3]
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You can actually make @user3030010's second answer more efficient by using numpy.lexsort(), using  **arr  mapped with dist()**  as key, and then applying the resulting mask to **arr** itself

```
import numpy as np

my_key = np.vectorize(lambda coord: dist(1, 1, coord[0], coord[1]))(arr)
inds = np.lexsort(keys = [my_key])
arr = arr[inds]
```

It is indeed a minor improvement but the method is particularly useful if you then add more keys for sorting.